# Config differents external proxy to every VM with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, virtualization, proxy

I have a virtualization server with one IP and 5 VM. To get internet access and ssh access in every VM I do this in

-------------/etc/network/interfaces-------

```
auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static
address 192.168.0.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
bridge_ports none
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE

post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 1022 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:22 
post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 1022 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:22
```

---

This is ok. Now I need set a different external proxy to every VM. For example: VM 192.168.0.1 used this proxy `user:pass@11.12.13.14:3218` to access the internet.

How can I do it?  Is it possible using only iptables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify - what do you want.

At first - iptables work only with packets.
It can't set user and password for proxy.

But you can set redirect traffic from each VM(it's ipadress) to each own proxy server.
I think
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s vm_ipaddress -p tcp —dport 80 -j DNAT —to proxy_ipaddress:port 
should help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I need to set one proxy per VM. I have external (another isp) proxies configured with squid. I would like to avoid implement this into each VM's OS. How can I do that using iptables or any service?

Comment: If you need separate proxy per VM, you can do it on host machine, as described below.
May be you may want to write automation script like
    * read proxy from any source(file, database, etc)
    * read VM ip addresses from VM API.
    * create iptables rule: foreach vm_ip do: set_proxy proxy_ip:port